# how to find $id based on detaol siswa then saved into database

Tags: laravel

i want to save into table "penyakit" **siswa_id** based on detail **siswa** on siswa_id in URL,, URL siswa is like this

[image]

siswa_id is **225** from table **siswa**

this is my function,

```
public function simpanData(Request $request, Siswa $id)
{

    $sekolah_id = \Auth::user()->sekolah_id;
    $siswa = Siswa::where('id',$id)->first();

    $data = [];

  foreach($request->nama_penyakit as $key => $v)
  {
    $data[] = 
    [
    'sekolah_id' => $sekolah_id,
    'siswa_id' => $siswa,
    'tingkat_pendidikan_id' => $request->tingkat_pendidikan_id[$key],
    'nama_penyakit' => $request->nama_penyakit[$key],
    'jenis_penyakit' => $request->jenis_penyakit[$key],
    'lama_sakit' => $request->lama_sakit[$key],
    'tahun' => $request->tahun[$key],
    'keterangan' => $request->keterangan[$key],
    ];
    dd($data);
    Penyakit::insert($data);
  }
}
```

this is my **Penyakit** Model

```
........................

protected $table = 'penyakit';

protected $fillable = [
    'sekolah_id', 'semester_id', 'kelas_id', 'tingkat_pendidikan_id',
     'siswa_id', 'tahun', 'jenis_penyakit', 'nama_penyakit', 'lama_sakit', 'keterangan',
];
```

column **siswa_id** already in $fillable..

but when i submit from,, result **dd** like this:
[image]

**siswa_id** alwasy NULL,,

this is my form action:

```
<form action="{{route('dataBaru.simpan_data', $siswa->id)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
```

this is my route for **simpanData** method

```
Route::post('penyakit/simpan/{id}','PenyakitController@simpanData')->name('dataBaru.simpan_data');
```

but WHY is **siswa_id** alwasy NULL.. whats wrong about my code ?
plis help , Thanks

Comment: print $id and check is siswa_id getting?

Comment: where did `$id` came from? ..if you are getting`$id` from url you can use `Request()->id`

Comment: $id from detail siswa

Comment: check the request data,
$id must not be null to have results in your query

Comment: when $request->data is null

Comment: its SOLVED with change public function (Request $request, $id) without Siswa